# Could not find gem 'mocha (= 0.12.3) x86-mingw32'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I try to launch redmine from IDE:

> rails/redmine/script/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development

but I am getting error:

> ```
> /resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'mocha (= 0.12.3) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
> ```

I installed mocha:

```
gem install mocha
```

But error still appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing it with the same exact version:

```
gem install mocha -v '0.12.3'
```